# Ubuntu server periodically unreachable

Tags: networking, firewall, debugging

I have an Ubuntu Server 14.04 server running. The server has two NICs and acts as a NAT router, with the help of [shorewall](http://shorewall.net/). Shorewall also acts as a plain firewall for blocking ports that I don't want to be open.

The way things are set up, server accepts SSH connections and replies to pings on its external/internet-facing NIC.
Shorewall is configured to allow both these kinds of traffic, and all of this it works - *sometimes*.

**However**, pretty often - at irregular intervals - the server stops responding to any kind of outside network traffic.
That means pings time out (no response), no new SSH connections can be established, and established connections are dropped.

I cannot find anything about this in my `sylog`, `kern.log` or [`shorewall.log`](https://serverfault.com/a/591746/133759).

**What could this *vaguely* defined behavior be? Where should I start looking for errors?**

## What I tried so far:

### Am I using the right host name/IP address?

YES! I am running [no-ip](http://www.noip.com/)'s [ddns client](http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client-on-ubuntu/) named `noip2`. I am using the NoIP hostname to contact my server. Additionally, I've observed that the server's external IP did not change, since `dhclient` logs (to `syslog`) that its IP lease is extended every so often.

### Is my ISP to blame?

Not as far as I can tell. In fact, I have a technical contact over there, and he reassured me that there was no service outage of any kind.
I have also used a VPN to get *away* from the place that I usually connect to the server *from*. That didn't help either.